# getting null view inside gridview of buttons of Dialog android

Tags: android, gridview, dialog

I am not able to access the buttons which are in gridview. My gridview is placed on dialog using customAdpater. Please help me!!!
Below is my code

1) In onCreate() method:

```
    dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.question_pallet);
            dialog.setTitle("Question Pallet...");
            gridView = (GridView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

            gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(QuestionBankActivity.this,allQuestions));
Button b = (Button) gridView.findViewWithTag("Hi"); //returning null
Button b = (Button) gridView.getChildAt(0); //returning null
```

2) question_pallet.xml is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="70dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >  

</GridView>
```

3) ImageAdapter.java for my grdview is

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity mContext;

List<GATEQuesAnswer> allQuestions;
static Button b[] = new Button[65] ;
int next_counter = 1;

private int pos;
// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Activity c, List<GATEQuesAnswer> allgeteQuestions){
    mContext = c;
    allQuestions = allgeteQuestions;
}

public ImageAdapter(QuestionBankActivity questionBankActivity) {
    mContext = questionBankActivity;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 65;
}



@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {           
    Button button;
    //if (convertView == null) {
        button = new Button(mContext);
        button.setText(Integer.toString(pos++));
        button.setId(position);
        button.setTag("Hi");

    //}
    //else
    //{
        //button = (Button) convertView;
        //Log.i("mytag", b.length+"");
    //}

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            ((QuestionBankActivity)mContext).navigate_to_ques(position+1);

        }
    });
    button.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
    return button;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

I have tried all possiblities like giving unique ids to each button and getting it using gridview.findViewById(),or getChildAt(index) but nothing is working:(
Any help will be appreciated!!!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

your getView method is all wrong , try it with something like ...

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder = null;
            Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.button = (Button) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.ID_OF_YOUR_BUTTON);
                holder.button.setTag("HI");
                convertView.setTag(holder);

                holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                              //DO YOUR CODE
                    }
                });

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            return convertView;
        }
    }


private class ViewHolder {
                    Button button;
        }
```

**//EDIT**

Also, You can iterate over all children of a **GridView**(or any other ViewGroup) with getChildAt():

```
for(int i=0; i<gridView.getChildCount(); i++) {
    Button child = (Button) gridView.getChildAt(i);
    // do stuff with child view
}
```

**row.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer:) But it gives me error.I am new to android please elaborate more.Code which I dont understand is                                    1) I got error at line no 5 on getActivity() is not defined when I replaced getActivity() with my context object the error gone! I dont know wheter this is right or wrong..2)what is R.layout.row?                                              3)I dont have buttons on xml so what shoud I provide R.id.ID_of_your _button                                                         Please help me out in this issue.

Comment: 1) its OK ... you did a right thing (the code i passed was design for fragments) and know i know its for activity ... so nevermind 2) ive edit the answer, you can find R.layout.row there 3) R.id.button1

Comment: Hi still it is not working I think I am wrong somewhere may be in onCreate() method Please review my code and give me suggetions..

Comment: Can anyone provide me sample example whose output should be like dynamically created dialog with custom layout. The layout should contain gridview with many buttons. up to this I have achieved in my code but when I get back to previous screen I am not able to get refernce of any of the button on dialog:(